# Is there any way to dump Internet Explorer settings to a textfile?

Tags: internet-explorer, settings

Topic says it all. Some stuff aren't working on some of my clients' browsers, and we have narrowed it down to an IE-error, but it would be GREAT to have a way of easily comparing IE's settings.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 10):

If on XP and up:
in command prompt, enter (with quotes!) for current user settings:

```
reg export "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" ie_hkcu.txt
```

in command prompt, enter (with quotes!) for machine settings:

```
reg export "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" ie_hklm.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

If this is on XP or Vista, try running `gpedit.msc`, then navigate to `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration-> Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer`. Right click on Internet Explorer and you'll be able to export all the settings.

If you need to do this programmatically, you could try looking at the IE registry settings in the hive.

Comment: On XP, at least, this does not export the whole tree recursively. You need to navigate to each level and export it separately.

Comment: This procedure will dump default (!) settings of IE only, so changes to the settings of Internet Explorer made by stuff will not be visible in dump.

Answer (score 2):

Related to John Feminella 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657926/is-there-any-way-to-dump-internet-explorer-settings-to-a-textfile/657943#657943)...  If you can not see the "Internet Explorer" as an option under `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration-> Administrative Templates > Windows Components`

1. Right click on Administrative Templates

   choose Add/Remove Templates

   choose the Add... button

   from the file selector choose to add the inetres template (inetres.adm). 
   I found that template on WinXP within the C:\Windows\inf

However - the export all function does not seem to act recursively, nor does it provide details on the settings.

Alternative method - try "[BackRex Internet Explorer Backup](http://www.backsettings.com/internet-explorer-backup.html)"